# what happens to std::vector storage after std::move()

Tags: c++, stl

I am calling `std::vector.reserve()` then I call `std::move()` on that vector object. Do I need to allocate space again? Does move changes the capacity of the vector?

Comment: `std::move` is just a cast. It does nothing to the object. It onky changes the type of the reference. You are interested in the subsequent move constructor/move assignment.

Comment: The content of a vector which was the source of a move assignment or moved copy constructor can be guessed from the [allocator requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements). All implementation do their best to avoid unnecessary memory allocation, so in practice, if the allocator allowes it, the moved from object has a null capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [move constructor for vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)[6] only guarantees that `other.empty() == true` (`other` being the moved-from object) after the move happens, it doesn't guarantee anything about the `capacity()` of the moved-from vector. So you can't be sure if it does or doesn't change the capacity.

So, to answer your question:

> Does move changes the capacity of the vector?

This is unspecified.

Comment: not specified, though would be rather strange if  a vector does not steal the actual memory when move constructed or if the moved from would allocate new memory

Comment: @user463035818 Well that's true but can't make guarantees on it ^^